# What is the best software for drawing tooltips?

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

We are currently using "Snagit" to take screenshots and add tooltips on top of them. These screenshots are later displayed on our site explaining features of our products.

Our goal is to find similar software to Snagit that allows to draw tooltips, but with a lot nicer design of tooltips, since the design of tooltips in Snagit looks very outdated.

I am attaching an example of screenshots with tooltips we are currently using.

Thank you for your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: You can edit what the tooltip looks like in snagit, or atleast you could do that but they keep removing features. But i agree maybe the tooltips should be actual HTML elements on your webpage.

Comment: @joojaa, Thank you for your reply. Please note that I am not trying to design HTML tooltips. What I am looking for, is a software that allows to draw tooltips that have nicer design than Snagit.

Answer (score 2):

If you are displaying tooltips on a website, then you wouldn't create those with a graphics package (except maybe the mockups) - You would create them directly with code (CSS). https://css-tricks.com/bubble-point-tooltips-with-css3-jquery/ is one example.

Comment: Hello mayersdesign, thank you for your reply. However I am not looking for Jquery equivalent, I need a graphic software that allows to draw the tooltips with nicer design that Snagit. Please let me know if you can suggest anything. Thanks

Comment: Hi Kelvin. Photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

Probably it exists, but I do not get an application to just do that.

My approach would be using a vector based program, so this tooltips can be edited and re used.

First, [define a style](https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=modern%20tooltip%20style&espv=2&site=webhp&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb0ePI-7XTAhVPxmMKHWCXBwgQ_AUIBigB&biw=1920&bih=1132). Background and font.

As you can notice, normally you can simply use a rectangle, or rounded shape, and choose some gradients, shadows, etc.

After this you simply re export your image, preferably using the exact same resolution as the original imported screen capture.

A free program I wold use is Inkscape, but you can use Illustrator, Corel Draw or Afinity Designer.

If you want your images to look good, put a little effort into it, and once you have them you can reuse your assets and do this very quickly

Comment: This is basicallybwhat imsaying but i feel that this may be overkill for the OP. Dunno.

Comment: Hello Rafael, thank you for your suggestions. If I cannot find all-in-one solution that includes tooltips (preferably with different templates), I will  follow your approach. The screenshots are taken and annotated by our content managers and I just wanted to make their life easier by giving them simple tool to use. However If our designers can design tooltip that can be copied on top of the screenshots, we probably can do it this way as well.

Comment: @Kelvin simple is often taken to mean limited... But this does  ot have to be the case. Operating illustrator on a superficial level is no harder than using the snagit editor for example. It just scales better.

Answer (score 0):

I do use snagit, and i never use the inbuilt editor. While i agree that doing this with web features is a good solution its not always practical. What is do instead is open the screen capture into my graphics editor, either illustrator or photoshop in my case. But could be any application.

By using this feature it you are able to change your initial question to a form what application can annotate my pictures as better than snagit? Now this is a question that is easily answered. Nearly any image editing application can do this, but which apps are is as easily usable as snagits editor? LOts of options out there.

Comment: Hello Joojaa, thats exactly what I need, a software that allows to annotate pictures but with nicer design than Snagit. Sorry if my question was not clear. Please note that I am not looking for HTML or Jquery solutions. Hope you can suggest something.

Comment: @Kelvin Ikkustrator or inkscape can be pretty effective